# CSS - make list wrap to fit viewport height

Tags: html, css

I want to make a  wrap it's content to the right so it fits the browser height.

As you can see in the screenshot the list doesn't fit onto the screen.

[image]

Example:

```css
#dropdown-menu-id
{
  display: block !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu-id">
  <li id="menu-item-816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-816"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/egg/">Egg</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-817"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/alberschwende/">Alberschwende</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-818" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-818"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/andelsbuch/">Andelsbuch</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-819" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-819"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/au/">Au</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-820" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-820"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/bezau/">Bezau</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-854" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-854"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/bizau/">Bizau</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-856" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-856"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/buch/">Buch</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-858" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-858"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/damuls/">Damüls</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-860" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-860"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/doren/">Doren</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-862" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-862"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/hittisau/">Hittisau</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-864" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-864"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/krumbach/">Krumbach</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-866" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-866"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/langenegg/">Langenegg</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-868" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-868"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/lingenau/">Lingenau</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-870" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-870"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/mellau/">Mellau</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-872" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-872"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/reuthe/">Reuthe</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-874" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-874"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/riefensberg/">Riefensberg</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-876" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-876"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/schnepfau/">Schnepfau</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-878" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-878"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/schoppernau/">Schoppernau</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-880" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-880"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/schrocken/">Schröcken</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-882" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-882"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/schwarzenberg/">Schwarzenberg</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-884" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-884"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/sibratsgfall/">Sibratsgfäll</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-886" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-886"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/sulzberg/">Sulzberg</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">Warth</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">12</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">11</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">10</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">9</a></li><li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">8</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">7</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">6</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">5</a></li><li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">4</a></li><li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">3</a></li><li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-destination menu-item-888"><a href="http://localhost/index.php/destination/bregenzerwald/warth/">1</a></li>
 </ul>
```

As you can see the list doesnt fit into the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options...

## Option 1: List is viewport height.

In this option, your list will be capped by the height of the screen and become scrollable.

```
ul{
  background:#CCC;
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

The key code to pay attention to here is `height:100vh` or *"Height is 100% of the Viewport's Height."* and the `overflow:auto;` or *"hide and make the overflowed text scrollable."*

## Option 2: List has max height.

In this option you will define a height, for example, `200px` and set the overflow to auto.

```
ul{
  background:#EEE;
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

You can see both versions on my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kg5dde6t/1/)** here.

Comment: Option the best: set list to "position: absolute" then set "top" and "bottom" properties.

Comment: @ether Thank you, really helped me :)